# Android Firebase Remote Config: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Whenever I call `FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()`, I get this warning:

`W/zze: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.`

I've updated the json config file from Firebase, but it remains the same. It does not affect any functionality, but I can't help but think something is missing. Any configurations I might be missing somewhere?

Comment: I've got the same warning too (using RemoteConfig), and I can confirm that all works fine. I've found something also in Flutter [repo issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28397). Something we could follow up.

Comment: Also filed an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/254) to ask for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning has been solved in `firebase-config 19.0.2`.

So if you upgrade the library to this version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.2'
```

the warning disappears.

Anyway even if this warning polluted our log messages, applications using the previous versions of firebase config did behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me.
I use Flutter project

adding `await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 0));` and `await remoteConfig.activateFetched();`

```
  void _adminValidate() async {
    try{
      final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;
      await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 0));
      await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
      print(remoteConfig.getString('admin'));
    }catch (e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
```